# How to integrate into the teams meeting experience

Tags: microsoft-teams, microsoft-live-meeting

Apart from an article from the verge announcing the capability, I can't find any developer documentation related to this functionality (tab/other interactive panel inside "the meeting experience").
Unless I'm looking in the wrong place, of course...

Has anyone been able to/found resources for integrating into the teams meeting experience?

Article: https://www.theverge.com/2020/7/21/21332414/microsoft-teams-third-party-apps-calls-meetings-integration-features

Comment: Are you trying to add app to meeting? if yes, could you please check this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/apps-in-teams-meetings/teams-apps-in-meetings)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add app to the meeting,  The meeting app can deliver a user experience for each stage of the meeting lifecycle including pre-meeting, in-meeting and post-meeting app experience, depending on the attendee's status.Please check this [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/apps-in-teams-meetings/teams-apps-in-meetings) for more info.

Comment: Thanks, somehow my initial search didn't turn up that section of their docs; I'll try to share a summary of the actual capabilities as improvement on your answer soon.